# Sklearn LinearRegression shapes not alligned

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

I'm trying to use sklearn for a linear regression prediction.

I have two lists of numbers(age in seconds sinds 1970) and some price.

When I try to predict my line I get the following error:

ValueError: shapes (1,1000) and (14697,14697) not aligned: 1000 (dim 1) != 14697 (dim 0)

My code:

```
inkoop = np.asarray(list(df['Bedrag_Inkoop_Ingediend_Mono']),dtype=np.number)
tempT = list(df['dtGeboorteDatum'])

dtAge = np.asarray([(time-datetime.date(1970,1,1)).total_seconds() for time in tempT],dtype=np.number)

dtAgeTestY = dtAge[-1000:]
dtAgeTrainY = dtAge[:-1000]
inkoopTestX = inkoop[-1000:]
inkoopTrainX = inkoop[:-1000]
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(inkoopTrainX,dtAgeTrainY.reshape(1,-1))
agePredictY = regr.predict(inkoopTestX.reshape(1,-1))

# The coefficients
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)

# The mean squared error
print("Mean squared error: %.2f"
      % mean_squared_error(inkoopTest, agePredictY))

# Explained variance score: 1 is perfect prediction
print('Variance score: %.2f' % r2_score(inkoopTest, agePredictY))

plt.scatter(inkoopTestX, dtAgeTestY,  color='black')
plt.plot(dtAgeTestY, agePredictY, color='blue', linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

He errors on agePredictY = regr.predict(inkoopTestX.reshape(1,-1)). I also tried without reshaping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reshaping your `X` input to the `predict` method, but not the `X` input to the `fit` method. You should only do one or the other. 
For example

```
X = inkoop.reshape(-1, 1) # many rows, one feature
trainX = X[:1000]
testX = X[-1000:]
regr.fit(trainX, trainY)
regr.predit(testX)
```